# Cordova how to remove console-via-logger.js?

Tags: javascript, cordova, logging

I faced with issue in Cordova 5.3.3. In code i'm using console.log/error, but in chrome debugger is always displayed logger message with source in console-via-logger.js. But this is wrong for me, i would like to have information from where from code is console.log comming.

How can i update this please?

Many thanks for any advice.